# Playing The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt's Gwent only

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

I want to play all Gwent matches in The Witcher 3 without going through the whole game. Is this possible?

The expansions and the DLCs have introduced lots of new cards and matches so I was wondering if there is a way in game to go through all matches one by one to unlock cards and play against the opponents you meet during the game.

A mod to the game that does that is also fine if the game doesn't support that natively.

Comment: How about... [Gwent the game?](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1284410/GWENT_The_Witcher_Card_Game/)

Comment: @TimmyJim tried that, but sadly it's a totally different experience from the Witcher 3's Gwent :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in-game or with any mod. You can not skip the story and do an only Gwent run.

There is also no [Gwent speedrun category](https://www.speedrun.com/the_witcher_3_wild_hunt/full_game), so the information for the fastest way to get to all of the Gwent NPC's is going to be really hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only Gwent plays, I don't know the panorama of the mods present, but you could simply play the story in superfacile mode and focus on looking for the cards from the merchants. You can get many cards from specific missions and some characters who meet over time during history.

If you just like Gwent play the new [Gwent](https://www.playgwent.com/it)